# How to translate Global:PHP in the view?

Tags: views

I need translate view's global:php in the no results behaviour,Can i do that? 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by using your text inside **[t()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7)**.

`t('your text to display');` or `t($string);`

Comment: where is green tick?

Comment: @wuchuan if this answer solve your question check it as accepter, of you don't know how read this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @Abin you look look